# Calling Camel JMS-Endpoint without using camelproxy

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel, spring-jms

I have created a jms endpoint and able to invoke it from the client width the camel:proxy in spring xml file.
now i want to be able to call the JMS endpoint directly without using the Spring/Camel Proxy. I want to call it via a URL.

How can i do this

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camel queue can be published to using the following

```
public DirectJMSRemotingClient() throws JMSException {
    factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerURL);
    connection = factory.createConnection();
    connection.start();
    session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Destination destination = session.createQueue("queueName");
    producer = session.createProducer(destination);
}

public void sendMessage() throws JMSException {

    TextMessage myTextMsg = session.createTextMessage();

    myTextMsg.setText("Hello World");
    System.out.println("Sending Message: " + myTextMsg.getText());
    producer.send(myTextMsg);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DirectJMSRemotingClient client = new DirectJMSRemotingClient();
    client.sendMessage();
}
```

And the Route Can be defined in camel like this

```
    <route>
        <from uri="jms:queue:queueName" />
        <setExchangePattern pattern="InOut" />
        <to uri="seda:camel-handler" />
    </route>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ProducerTemplate API in Camel to send a message to any kind of Camel endpoint/component.

See details at: http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html